# Algorithm to parse a config file in php (Doxygen file)

Tags: php, algorithm, configuration-files, doxygen

I have a conf file like this: http://pastie.org/768582 and my goal is to get in an array the comments and the key/value of each keys.

`array(
    array(`

```
    'comment' => "The PROJECT_NAME tag is a single",

    'key' => "PROJECT_NAME",

    'value' => "JMK",
),
```

)

I would know what algoritm do I have to use?

I have already transform the content of the configuration file to an array (line by line) with explode() function.

Now I am trying to get all the comment lines while next line begins with '# ' and the couple key/value but it is here that I have trouble.

If someone have an idea it would be nice. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the key/value pairs, but not the comments:

```
$options = array();

foreach ($line as $l)
{
  $l = trim($l);
  if (strlen($l) && substr($l, 0, 1) != '#')
  {
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $l);

    // remove whitespace from the end of the config key
    $key = rtrim($key);

    $options[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one way

```
$content = file_get_contents("file");
$s = preg_split("/#--*/",$content);
$y = preg_split("/\n\n/",end($s));
for($i=0;$i<count($y)-1;$i++){
    if ($y[$i]){
        if (strpos($y[$i],"#")!==FALSE){
            $comment="$y[$i]\n";
            $conf=$y[$i+1];
            $cs = array_map(trim,explode("=",$conf));
            $A["comment"]=$comment;
            $A["key"]=$cs[0];
            $A["value"]=$cs[1];
            $TA[]=$A;
        }
    }
}
print_r($TA);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment] => # This tag specifies the encoding used for all characters in the config file
# that follow. The default is UTF-8 which is also the encoding used for all
# text before the first occurrence of this tag. Doxygen uses libiconv (or the
# iconv built into libc) for the transcoding. See
# http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv for the list of possible encodings.

            [key] => DOXYFILE_ENCODING
            [value] => UTF-8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [comment] => # The PROJECT_NAME tag is a single word (or a sequence of words surrounded
# by quotes) that should identify the project.

            [key] => PROJECT_NAME
            [value] => JMK
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [comment] => # The PROJECT_NUMBER tag can be used to enter a project or revision number.
# This could be handy for archiving the generated documentation or
# if some version control system is used.

            [key] => PROJECT_NUMBER
            [value] => 10
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), the format looks compatible. It won't process the comments, though.

Comment: unfortunately the file doesn't seems to be well formated. See the comments '#' instead of ';' the first special character like '(' outputs an error. I think I will do otherwise.

Comment: Infact the doxygen configuration file looks similary to a Makefile. I will look if PHP can parse easily Makefile.